# How to change the BorderStyle for a Panel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a panel `System.Windows.Forms.Panel`

with property

```
BorderStyle="FixedSingle"
```

It render with a gray color border.

I need:

- to be able to set the color and the thickness if possible for the border.
- I am interested to know if it also possible hide completely the border.

Any idea how to solve this?

Code for my control:

```
OptimizedPanel : Panel



 <WindowsFormsHost Name="WinFormsHost">
        <wh:OptimizedPanel x:Name="RenderingPanel"
                           BorderStyle="None"  />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the color or thickness, I believe you have to set `BorderStyle.None` and draw the border yourself.

If you want to hide the border, you can use the value `BorderStyle.None`, which also happens to be the default.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.borderstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have edit my question. My panel it is inside a WindowsFormsHost both are displayed on top of a WPF application. In this scenario even setting BorderStyle.None I see a border. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Windows.Forms.Form.Panel control does not support border color. So, you cannot set border color directly. But you can draw your own border using graphics object.

```
private void pnlPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width - 1, this.ClientRectangle.Height - 1);
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, r);
}
```

Dont forget to set `BorderStyle` property to `None`

```
pnlPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am interested to know if it also possible hide completely the border.

Yes, just try this:

```
           panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension class of panel and override the paint method. Then you can draw whatever border you like when the panel is repainted.

As far as I am aware there is no method for border colours included with panel by default.

As for hiding the border simply `BorderStyle.None`